# Swift Class Inheritance

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In my game there is a GameScene.swift file. I wanted to create a whole different .swift file for my main character lets say a redball.swift. In the redball.swift file I declared redBall to equal a skspritenode. How would I use that sprite in my main GameScene.swift file?

Comment: just use it. what is the problem? do you have any error message to show?

Answer (score 0):

Some code would be helpful (I can only infer from your question that RedBall is inheriting from SKSpriteNode, but I could be wrong, please correct me) but if you have set it up as follows:

In redball.swift

```
class RedBall: SKSpriteNode{
}
```

Then in GameScene.swift

```
var mainCharacter = RedBall()
```